# Python 3.7 - search value from excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf

i am a new coder (never done b4) and i'm learning python (v. 3.7) and i have a problem. I would like to upload a PDF (already converted to text), extract values from excel (done ! -already converted to text) and search that values in the pdf (searchable). If it founds the value it gives an output with the same value ! 
How can i do ?
here the code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel ('FDE.xlsx', index_col=0, usecols="A:D")
```

read PDF:

```
import PyPDF2
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('C:/Users/Desktop/ABC/Newpdf.pdf', 'rb'))

pdf_get_page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
pdf_get_page.extractText()
```

Button where i would like to insert the commands:

```
btn1 = Button(root, text ="Importa valori",padx=36, pady=10)
btn1.pack(pady=10)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Albert! Could you post the code that you've written so far (just the part that you're confused about) and what you expect it to do?

Comment: hey Afterlife ! i have updated my question with codes. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Albert_programmer is this problem solved?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 actually nope =(

Comment: does my answer help- or is it missing something?

Comment: probably it would help if i would be more confident with python...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly of searching the same values in `PDF` that is also present in `Excel` then you can take a simple approach of reading both the contents of the files and use a `for` loop to iterate through them, and when they match you can print it.

For Excel, read the data into a `List`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsm', sheetname=0) # can also index sheet by name or fetch all sheets
mylist = df['column name'].tolist() # set many column as you like
```

For `Pdf` use a `split(" ")` method to form the contents into a list.

```
pdfContents = pageObj.extractText().split(" ")
```

You can then iterate through a nested for loop checking for matching values

```
for txt in pdfContents:
  for cell_value in mylist:
      if txt == cell_value:
         print(txt) 
         # do whatever you want here
```

Note that this approach introduces `o(n^2)` which as data grows becomes inefficient.